# What is the difference between a maven root dependency and a direct dependency?

Tags: maven, aether

In the [aether docs](https://maven.apache.org/resolver/apidocs/org/eclipse/aether/collection/CollectRequest.html) it says that there are three ways to build a dependency graph, to specify a root dependency or a list of direct dependencies.

[image]

What is the differences between specifying a root dependency and specifying a list of direct dependencies?

Comment: Can explain why do you need that? and what kind of problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm just looking to understand a bit more about aether.